# QWidget created by Qt designer not recognized as QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am using Qt designer 4.8.7, beginning with it. I have created a `MainWindow` in which I'd like to load a layout.

I have a widget, generated with `pyuic4` from Qt designer.

I load my widget doing

```
self.setCentralWidget(myWidget)
```

It throws this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_myWidget' object has no attribute 'setObjectName'
```

It clearly explains the object passed is not recognized as a QWidget. The problem can be solved modifying the class definition from:

```
class Ui_myWidget(object):
```

to

```
class Ui_myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
```

Since widgets will be updated, each time the `.py` will be generated again, I'll have to manually edit. I'd like to avoid this. Did I miss a step?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the .py files generated by `pyuic4` at all, if possible. Instead you create a new .py file right next to them and import those files to call the widgets: `from pyfilename import Ui_myWidget`

Comment: This was for test purpose. The provided answer from @eyllanesc explains it also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of Qt Designer is to implement the view, so it does not implement a QWidget, we have the duty to use that implementation through a widget, I recommend doing the following:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_myWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Then you create the object of this class and use it in your other widget:

```
myWidget = MyWidget(self)
self.setCentralWidget(myWidget)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation behind. This works like a charm

Comment: I need to wait at least 3 minutes to. Wait a minute

Comment: Sorry, I did not know about that rule.

Comment: Me neither. I have to say, it was surprising to get the perfect answer this fast